# Server response really slow with a lot of connection

Tags: c#, grapevine

I'm setting a Rest server using Grapevine, this works good. But when run the clients, and this make around 50~ connections per second, this gets very slow reply.

I create a route call "/debug", in this I show the time taken from the begin of request to end request, and this show to me around 50ms, but in Postman, the total request take 5-20s per request.

I think Grapevine internal process takes a lot of time with a lot of connection.

I try to change Connections value from 50 to 200, and this not work.

```cs
 server = new RestServer();

server.Port = Config.Data["Listener"]["port"];
server.Host = Config.Data["Listener"]["domain"];
server.Connections = 200;
Console.Info("Connection Number: "+server.Connections);

server.Start();
server.Router.Register(typeof(Default));
server.Router.BeforeRouting += ValidateKey;
```

The code takes around 10~100ms to complete, but the connection takes around 5~20s to complete. I need this to take less time in connection.

Comment: Sounds like you need better WiFi.

Comment: WTF? There running in a VPS server, the clients too, the VPS has 100MB upload and upload, and I check, this only use 40~MB aprox.

Comment: What version of Grapevine are you using?

Comment: Also be aware that the `Connections` property has been deprecated. see https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/blob/master/src/Grapevine/Server/ServerSettings.cs#L34

Comment: Can you post more code? I can't really help based solely on the what you've posted here. Alternatively, try upgrading to Grapevine 5, as it is much faster overall and is async all through the stack.